# Twitter Search API - Popular tweets not working

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am experiencing an issue with the Twitter Search API. I am trying to grab the total amount of retweets for the 100 most popular tweets, for the subject the user gives.

I am trying to achieve this with this code.

```
<?php
  //Debugging
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  //Include Tokens file
  require_once('tokens.php');
  //Include Auth lib
  require_once('twitterAuth/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

  //Grab subject from url
  $subject = $_GET["subject"];

  //Request
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
  $getfield = '?q='.$subject.'&count=100&result_type=popular';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';
  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
  $result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
          ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
          ->performRequest();

        $json_output = json_decode($result, true); //getting the file content as array
        $count = 0;
        $total = 0;
        foreach($json_output['statuses'] as $tweets) {
            $count = intval($tweets['retweet_count']);
            $total = $total + $count;
        }
        echo '{"data":[{"retweet_count":'.$total.'}]}';
?>
```

While this code is working great when I use **result_type=mixed** or **result_type=recent**, it will, for some reason, not work when I change it to **result_type=popular** even-though the Twitter API has listed as an option in their documentation. [Twitter Search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) . It doesn't return any errors when I run the request, it doesn't show any feedback. When I replace popular with mixed or recent, the code works excellent. Been stuck on this for a while, help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will depend heavily on what you search for.  The Twitter search API only lets you retrieve Tweets from the past week.  If there were no popular tweets for that week, you won't see any results.

For example - a search for "Android" shows these popular results

https://snap.apigee.com/1KlHi9m

But if I search for "qwertyuiop" there are no results from the API

https://snap.apigee.com/1ZT56wV

Even though a normal Twitter search shows results https://twitter.com/search?q=qwertyuiop&src=typd